# Supporting unidirectional swipe in Android widgets

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In Android what is the best way of providing unidirectional horizontal navigation? To set the expectation, I have started writing Android application two months ago.

In my situation, I have a list of screen size images which user will see one by one. To see the next image user has to swipe left (right-to-left motion). Once an image is seen user should NOT be able to go back, hence for this purpose right swipe (left-to-right motion) has to be disabled.

I have used a custom ViewPager to achieve this where I have overridden onTouchEvent method as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        boolean lockScroll = false;

        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            lastX = ev.getX();
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (lastX >= ev.getX()) {
                lockScroll = false;
            } else {
                lockScroll = true;
            }

            lastX = ev.getX();
            break;
        }

        if (lockScroll) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
}
```

This works mostly. I mean almost always right swipes are blocked but in certain cases it happens which I am not able to figure out why. 
Any clues, where might be the problem or is there any other way of handling this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ViewPager#canScrollHorizontally](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#canScrollHorizontally%28int%29). It's a prime candidate for overriding.

Comment: Thanks Peter.I have been breaking my head over it for long. I curse myself now for not asking this question earlier on Stackoverflow. Wonderful site, wonderful people !

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Android development! One of the things you'll learn very quickly is never implement something that is already available open source. I recommend using the gallery function of https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, it will look a lot better and will be a lot more robust then if you or I made it ourselves.

Comment: many thanks for this link. Looks like this will be a one stop solution for my all image loading/displaying problems :)